# How to use useEffect to update and render the component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I was writing a function inside useEffect and calling that function in form but it says function defined but never used

I was using useEffect so that whenever the email is updated it should update and render the component freshly
Right now the component is not re-rendering on button click

```
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("")


    const handleEmailInput = (e) => {
        console.log("Entering email");
        setEmail(e.target.value);
    }

    const [validated, setValidated] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleSubmit = (event) => {
            const form = event.currentTarget;
            if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
            setEmail("")  
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
            } else{
            setModalShow(true)
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
            }
            setValidated(true);
        };
      }, [email]);
```

```
                    <Form noValidate validated={validated} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <Form.Group controlId="validationCustomUsername">
                            <InputGroup>
                                <InputGroup.Prepend>
                                    <InputGroup.Text id="inputGroupPrepend">@</InputGroup.Text>
                                </InputGroup.Prepend>
                                <Form.Control
                                    type="email"
                                    pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$"
                                    placeholder="Email"
                                    value = {email}
                                    onChange = {e=>handleEmailInput(e)}
                                    aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend"
                                    required
                                />
                                <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                                    Please enter an valid email.
                                </Form.Control.Feedback>
                            </InputGroup>
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Button type="submit" >Subscribe</Button>
                    </Form>
```

Comment: This is a job for [`useCallback()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) not `useEffect()` otherwise `handleSubmit` dies as soon as the scope of the `useEffect()` callback ends.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because you have never called the function inside useEffect -

```
useEffect(() => {
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        const form = event.currentTarget;
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
        setEmail("")  
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        } else{
        setModalShow(true)
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        }
        setValidated(true);
    };
    handleSubmit(some_value) // need to call this function//
  }, [email]);
```

Now whatever you are trying to do, I don't think will work. First of all your submit function that you are calling on onSubmit of form will never work because it's scope is not global. It is inside useEffect and it's scope is within useEffect. I think what you should be doing is remove useEffect, you don't need it. Keep your component like this -

```
 const [email, setEmail] = useState("")

const handleEmailInput = (e) => {
    console.log("Entering email");
    setEmail(e.target.value);
}

const [validated, setValidated] = useState(false);

   const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        const form = event.currentTarget;
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
        setEmail("")  
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        } else{
        setModalShow(true)
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        }
        setValidated(true);
    };


 <Form noValidate validated={validated} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <Form.Group controlId="validationCustomUsername">
                            <InputGroup>
                                <InputGroup.Prepend>
                                    <InputGroup.Text id="inputGroupPrepend">@</InputGroup.Text>
                                </InputGroup.Prepend>
                                <Form.Control
                                    type="email"
                                    pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$"
                                    placeholder="Email"
                                    value = {email}
                                    onChange = {e=>handleEmailInput(e)}
                                    aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend"
                                    required
                                />
                                <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                                    Please enter an valid email.
                                </Form.Control.Feedback>
                            </InputGroup>
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Button type="submit" >Subscribe</Button>
                    </Form>
```

Comment: Hi @Atin Singh earlier i was doing in this way working perfect , but i thought to use it inside useEffect.

Comment: @ParthTiwari Any specific reason for that? What were you trying to achieve ?